# react-native-flexi-radio-button onselect is not function

Tags: react-native

I want to use react-native-flexi-radio-button in my project to select one of the item in list form array and use this code

```
 {this.state.Rooms.map(function (value,index) {

                    console.log(value.id)

                    return(
                        <RadioGroup  onSelect ={(index, value) => this.onSelect(index, value)}>
                            <RadioButton value={value.id} isSelected={false} index={index}>
                                {/*<Text>{i.title}</Text>*/}
                            </RadioButton>
                        </RadioGroup>
                    )

                })

                }
```

but when i click on any button, it returns `_this3.onselect is not function` and its this function

```
  onSelect=(index,value)=>{
      console.log(index,value)
    }
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of the code

```
 {this.state.Rooms.map(function (value,index) {
```

to:

```
{this.state.Rooms.map((value,index) => {
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) thread to know the difference between arrow functions vs the usual function declaration